# Minimum character count text box

Tags: javascript, html, textinput

my code isn't working for some reason..here it is:

html:

```
<input type="text" name="post" maxlength="140" />
```

and for javascript:

```
var inpt = document.getElementsByName("post")[0];
// var inputValue=document.getElementById(post).value;
if (inpt.value < 10) {
    return false;
    alert("Post must be longer than 10 characters.");
} else {
return true;
}
```

i tried it with and without quoting the second line and both do nothing. also i made sure to change inpt.value to inputValue.length when i unquoted the second line.

Comment: Should be: `inpt.value.length < 10`.

Comment: @PHPglue still not working dude

Comment: Your code is probably defined before the `name='post'` Element. Use `onload` to overcome this. You should use external JavaScript referring to the `src` attribute of the script tag within the `<head>` using an onload event over your code like: `var pre = onload; onload = function(){ if(pre)pre(); /* run code here */ }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems

```
var inpt = document.getElementsByName("post")[0];

//need to test the length
if (inpt.value.length < 10) {
    alert("Post must be longer than 10 characters.");
    //return after the alert
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Also make sure that the script is triggered on an event

```js
function validate() {
  var inpt = document.getElementsByName("post")[0];

  //need to test the length
  if (inpt.value.length < 10) {
    alert("Post must be longer than 10 characters.");
    //return after the alert
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return validate()">
  <input type="text" name="post" maxlength="140" />
  <button>Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the alert before the return statement.